# Where did the term attorney (or simply its prevalence) originate?

Tags: united-states, legal-terms, lawyer, legal-history

In America there is no dichotomy between solicitors and barristers but simply attorneys at law, colloquially just lawyers.

Why are they not just solicitors or not just barristers?

Further we have attorneys general. Which seems to have replaced the solicitor general.

Then are there other types of attorneys than only legal ones?

Comment: Related: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/83707/whats-the-definition-of-an-attorney-at-law

Comment: Both the US and England-and-Wales have a solicitor general who is subordinate to the attorney general.  Where does the idea that one replaced the other come from?

Comment: Just my own incomplete understanding which now stands corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The US has kept the original meaning

More or less.

The [word](https://www.etymonline.com/word/attorney) entered English from Old French around the turn of the 14th century and meant a person appointed to handle the financial or legal affairs of another.

Two branches developed, a common attorney which leads to the modern concept of an attorney under a power of attorney, and an attorney at law. These were qualified people who prepared briefs for barristers in the Common Law courts. The attorneys equivalents in the Chancellery courts were called solicitors.

When the courts were merged in the UK in the late 19th century, the term solicitor was kept and attorney was abolished.

At about the same time, the courts in the US merged but the Americans kept attorney and abandoned solicitor. Solicitor is still used in some parts of the US to refer to a government lawyer, particularly in the office of [solicitor general](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solicitor_General_of_the_United_States).

The US as well as Commonwealth countries have both an Attorney General and a Solicitor General. The AG is usually a politician and the chief law officer of the government. The SG is usually a civil servant and represents the government in court; for example, when the USA needs to appear in SCOTUS it’s the SG that does it.

Comment: Attorneys equivalent in the chancellery courts were called solicitors, or barristers' equivalents?

Comment: Otherwise, top answer!

Comment: So did America also have both chancellery and common law courts in parallel?

Comment: Isn't the AG mainly just like the chief prosecutor?

Comment: Most U.S. states also have a solicitor general. At the federal level, the SG is mostly a SCOTUS specialist. In most states, the SG handles both state supreme court and SCOTUS cases.